# WPF - language changes only in MainWindow?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, dictionary, mergeddictionaries

I've programmed a choose-language option in my project, using MergedDictionaries and project's settings. The issue is **the language changes successfully only in my MainWindow**, and **not in other Windows** as well. What am I doing wrong?
Set-language func in MainWindow (**edit: MainWindow.cs**):

```
/*set language*/
    private void SetLanguageDictionary()
    {
        ResourceDictionary dict = new ResourceDictionary();
        if (Properties.Settings.Default.Language.Equals("en")) //english was set
        {
            dict.Source = new Uri("\\res\\enDictionary.xaml", UriKind.Relative);
        }
        else //otherwise - hebrew as default lang.
        {
            dict.Source = new Uri("\\res\\hebDictionary.xaml", UriKind.Relative);
        }
        //add required dictionary to the MergedDictionaries
        Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(dict);
    }
```

A small example of one of the Dictionaries [they are set symmetrically, if it matters]:

```
<ResourceDictionary 
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:UI_WPF"
xmlns:system="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">
<system:String x:Key="employees">Employees</system:String>
<system:String x:Key="employers">Employers</system:String>
<system:String x:Key="contracts">Contracts</system:String> </ResourceDictionary>
```

Comment: there is not enough information, if dictionary is not added its impossible to use it. that means somewhere you are merging the English dictionary which is causing this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't told us where the SetLanguageDictionary() method is defined but if you want to apply the resources globally you could merge the ResourceDictionary into the global Application.Current.Resources:

```
Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(dict);
```

Comment: That's it! Thank you [and other who helped too!], the SetLanguageDictionary() was set in MainWindow.cs (as edited), and the whole Application was needed to be affected.

Answer (score 1):

you know why language changes in MainWindow only? because when you call  `SetLanguageDictionary()`only  MainWindow will refresh(reload), and that why labels and texts will change. In order to change language in other window, you need to refresh them - reload them again- and during reloading process, content and labels will be updated.

you can call other window from MainWindow like below

```
window win = new window();
//then
win.AnyMethodyou_want();
```

`new window()` will  reload window  again, then language can be changed.

I have used this way before..